# Calculating relative difference to the first element in a vector

Tags: r

I have a number of vectors of the following form:

```
vector1 <- c(42.000, 40.781, 40.625, 40.312, 40.375, 40.344, 39.531, 39.875, 40.344, 39.500, 39.125, 39.062, 39.656)

vector2 <- c(24.625, 25.625, 24.844, 25.250, 26.250, 26.344, 26.250, 26.375, 26.250, 25.812, 27.000, 26.469, 26.781)
```

I would like to place these on a common base starting from 100 as the first value and for each new value taking the difference between the first value and the new value.

I used the following code:

```
i=13 

for (1 in 1:13) {

vector1[i]=(vector1[i]-vector1[i-1])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should read and understand `?"for"`.

Comment: Dear @dbr, please don't ask your R questions on CV -- SO is the place for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear, what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "starting from 100 as the first value"?

This gives the difference of all elements to the first element:

```
vector1 <- c(42.000, 40.781, 40.625, 40.312)
vector1-vector1[1]
#[1]  0.000 -1.219 -1.375 -1.688
```

This gives the difference to the first element divided by the first element:

```
(vector1-vector1[1])/vector1[1]
#[1]  0.00000000 -0.02902381 -0.03273810 -0.04019048
```

This gives differences between subsequent elements:

```
diff(vector1)
#[1] -1.219 -0.156 -0.313
```

Comment: yes I would like to have the difference of all elements to the first element divided by the first element, to get the absolute difference, but I would like to do this for all the values, so I would need a loop

Comment: @dbr You don't need a loop because R is vectorized. I added an example on how to calculate the relative difference to the first element.